# An argument where a person says exactly what you told them isn’t true?

Tags: single-word-requests, rhetorical-devices, psychology

**Background:**
Person A and Person B have been in a romantic relationship for many years.

Person A gives Person B a large sum of money, specifically telling them that that Person B can use this money wherever they like. Person A also emphasized that:

> “I don’t need to know the specifics about where or how you’ll use this money. I don’t
> want to be controlling.”

A few months later, Person B tells Person A that they are completely broke. Person A is confused; as they had just sent a large sum of money. Person A asks where it all went and it escalates into an argument. In this argument, Person B uses the exact same words Person A had used before, but against them:

> I didn’t know I was supposed to tell you all the specific details
> about how and where I spent it!”

My question is, what is the word for what Person B is doing? Using the exact words they said against them when that’s not the case — they are asking because it was money that was supposed to last many years.

Hope that makes sense. Thanks, and sorry if I made this post wrong, I’m very new around here but I hope to stay around and contribute!

Comment: Can you provide another example?

Comment: @Centaurus (sorry this is my first time on English stackexchange, I hope I’m doing this properly). Yes I can provide another example, but I think it’s better if I can clarify this one if there’s something you don’t understand in it.

Comment: The interpersonal element here may be stronger than the Engish question. Could be *gaslighting*, could be a misunderstanding. Not wanting to appear controlling is not the same as no strings attached.

Comment: .@Lana I've retagged because you're asking for the name of the device which Person B is employing (re-using A's words). A staple of [*-request] questions is a sample sentence with a gap for the word you want. Here, it's not precisely clear whether you want a verb or a noun, really. Another example might help to address @Yosef's comment, too.

Comment: More than likely, another example would help us find whether there is a word for the situation.

Comment: @Lana Someone has to write an answer (or, hopefully, there will be more than one); you can then accept the answer that fits your requirement best, and they can be voted on. You can even write an answer yourself. I'm going to remove answers in comments. I would strongly recommend you [edit] your question to include another example.

Comment: Following up on Centaurus' comments, the example you have given is very specific and peculiar, and may be looked at as an instance of different general phenomena. Without more examples, it is impossible to know which of these general phenomena you are seeking the name for.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are interested in the somewhat rhetorical device that consists in uttering more or less sarcastically the negative of a sentence that someone used once in the way of providing clues, advice, directives, etc., this repetition being intended to make more prominent the contradiction involved ; this sort of repetition "in the negative", if not said more or less sarcastically is just factual, and it seems difficult to associate with it a rhetorical device. If it is said in a tone that comes through as reproachful and contemptuous, it can be characterized in several ways.

One way to put that is to speak of a *sarcastic evocation*.

- "I didn’t know I was supposed to tell you all the specific details about how and where I spent it!” said B in a sarcastic evocation of A's words when A granted B the money.